# failing to open my homepage instead getting old warning messages from mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi  I tried to connect to mysql using the wrong password.  I finally made it there but now as I try to reach my homepage www.hari.se I just get following ;

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'hari.se'@'csea04.cliche.se' (using password: YES) in /home/virtual/hari.se/public_html/PHP/db.php on line 2  
Warning: mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/virtual/hari.se/public_html/PHP/db.php on line 3 
Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/virtual/hari.se/public_html/PHP/db.php on line 3  
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/virtual/hari.se/public_html/index.php on line 7  
Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/virtual/hari.se/public_html/index.php on line 7 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Please friends  anyone who can help? Hari

Comment: tried to connect to mysql using the wrong password ????

Answer (score 0):

your script is not able establish the connection to the database
also you should insert true information about the mysql connection into db.php file

and you can't insert the wrong password !!!!

you have some variable in this file

similar to below:

```
$database_hostname = 'localhost (as default) or your server hostname';
$database_username = 'root (as default) or your database username';
$database_password = '(in some local web servers we don't have any password for database but in hosting servers usually we have a defined password ) such as (3R8=&3pHEJ+J)';
$database_name = 'you must insert your database name in here';

$connection_mysql=mysql_connect($database_hostname,$database_username,$database_password);
mysql_select_db($database_name,$connection_mysql);
--------------
or in the simple mode might be similar below:
$connection_mysql=mysql_connect(localhost,your_database_name,your_database_password);
mysql_select_db($database_name,$connection_mysql);
```

i think your information is incorrect please check your entered information in db.php (also the low level Possibility is your account suspended or limited in server by admin)

Comment: $oneVar = 'JustTheWord'; // explanations in comments please